# Optimal office chair for levator scapulae problems

Tags: pain, ergonomics, posture

I am suffering from chronical neck pain caused by tension in the right levator scapulae. It does not matter how I sit on [my chair](http://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B00M6AJWHY/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_dp_ss_3?pf_rd_p=556245207&pf_rd_s=lpo-top-stripe&pf_rd_t=201&pf_rd_i=B0037UZ4A6&pf_rd_m=A3JWKAKR8XB7XF&pf_rd_r=1PV9AMFB2JGBVRMMGYQG), it hurts after a few minutes.

I tried chairs with a head rest and they help. However, in order to be pain free I need to sit in a very unnatural way with the head basically almost bend back into the neck resting on the head rest permanently and not moving. I looked like Stephen Hawking. That is unsustainable.

Are there any "wonder chairs" you could recommend in this case?